# How to assign variable in passing multiple ID's in java script function?

Tags: javascript, list, function, parameter-passing, function-call

I try to pass two id's from my list to function, But my function unable to recognize the id's.

My code as follow:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle(id1, id2)   {    
var ele = document.getElementById(id2);  
var text = document.getElementById(id1);  
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {  
            ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "NDEM10K";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "NDEM10K";
    }
} 
</script>
</head>
 <body>
 <ol>
    <li>
        <a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle(this.id);">NDEM10K</a> 
        <div id="toggleText" style="display: none" onclick="toggle(this.id);">
        <ul>
            <li>AP</li>
            <li>UP</li>
            <li>KA</li>
            <li>An</li>
            <li>ts</li>
        </ul>
            </div>
    </li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

My function unable to recognise id's. So, I want to assign id to a variable.

My Full code is here:

```
<html>
<head>


<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle(id1,id2) {
    var ele = document.getElementById(id1);
    var text = document.getElementById(id2);
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "NDEM10K";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "NDEM10K";
    }
} 


</script>
</head>
 <body>
 <ol>
    <li>
        <a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle(this.id);">NDEM10K</a> 
        <div id="toggleText" style="display: none" onclick="toggle(this.id);">

        <ul>
            States
            <li>Andhra</li>
            <li>Andhra</li>
            <li>Andhra</li>
            <li>Andhra</li>
            <li>Andhra</li>
        </ul>

            </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="dT" href="javascript:toggle(this.id);">NDEM50K</a> 
        <div id="tT" style="display: none" onclick="NDEM50K(this.id);">

        <ul>
            Districts
            <li>East Godavari</li>
            <li>West Godavari</li>
            <li>Krishna</li>
            <li>Vishaka</li>
            <li>Hyderabad</li>
        </ul>

            </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="2dT" href="javascript:toggle(this.id);">NDEM2K</a> 
        <div id="2tT" style="display: none" onclick="NDEM2K(this.id);">

        <ul>
            Districts
            <li>Hyderabad</li>
            <li>Kakinada</li>
            <li>Rajahmundry</li>
            <li>Vishaka</li>
            <li>Mumbai</li>
        </ul>

        </div>
    </li>

</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are passing only 1 `ID`!

Comment: I'm passing two id's one from anchor tag and another from div..

Comment: your call to toggle function pass only (this, id) so id1 will receive this and id2 will receive id

Comment: @agentpx that is not `(this, id)`, it is `(this.id)`

Comment: If I understand it correctly you have a function that expects two IDs, but while calling you will be passing only one ID. The requirement is that the function should get executed when it gets both the IDs. Is it correct ?

Comment: You are not passing two ids, you are calling function twice by passing only one `id`!

Comment: @satyachandra you bound the function twice, each with ONE argument, which doesn't equal to bind with two arguments.

Comment: Right i thought it is a comma, but the context is correct if it is. Sorry about that @Bharadwaj

Comment: @agentpx no problem ;) you suspected as you thought it could be :)

Comment: @Diptendu ya my intention is to access both id's..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing one id at a time, thats why your are getting error `property of undefined`. And why you want to pass id and create element in function, if you can pass elements itself in the function.

Try This:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <script language="javascript">
        function toggle(ele, text) {
            if (ele !== null && ele !== undefined && ele.style.display == "block") {
                ele.style.display = "none";
                text.innerHTML = "NDEM10K";
            }
            else {
                ele.style.display = "block";
                text.innerHTML = "NDEM10K";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <a id="displayText" onclick="toggle(this.nextSibling.nextSibling, this)"     href="#">NDEM10K</a> 
            <div id="toggleText" style="display: none" onclick="toggle(this, this.previousSibling.previousSibling);">
                <ul>
                    <li>AP</li>
                    <li>UP</li>
                    <li>KA</li>
                    <li>An</li>
                    <li>ts</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ol>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on everything you said in the comments I think you want this:

**This**

```
    <div id="toggleText" style="display: none" onclick="toggle(this.id);">
```

**Should Be**

```
    <div id="toggleText" style="display: none" onclick="toggle(this.id,this.parentNode.firstChild.id);">
```

Comment: I have replaced but not getting output !

Answer (score 0):

Since your `id`s will be constant strings, you can try by passing directly `id`s. Like,

`toggle('displayText','toggleText')`

Comment: I got by passing direct id's, Later I want to  implement for more lists, so I need to pass id's.

Comment: Yes, as far as ID's which you are passing won't change, you can pass them directly

Comment: Or if you add more information to your question what actually you need to achieve, may be its better to solve it completly

Comment: ok, then its better to pass `id` strings to the function as you are calling same function by passing different `id`s.